# Plasma keeps remounting my cifs share

Tags: kde, cifs, unmounting, plasma, kde4

I have this mount configured in /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.5.1   /mnt cifs auto,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-timeout=5 0 0
```

I've tried unmounting it every possible way:

```
umount /mnt
umount -t cifs /mnt
umount -i //192.168.5.1
umount -i /mnt
umount -a -t cifs -l
umount -r /mnt
...
```

I finally realized plasma was automatically remounting my share:

/var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 19 01:56:29 Linux systemd[1]: Got automount request for /mnt, triggered by 1548 (plasma-desktop)
Feb 19 01:56:29 Linux systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt...
Feb 19 01:56:29 Linux systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt.
```

So, what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After  too much search, I finally found the culprit:

.kde/share/config/kded_device_automounterrc:

```
[Devices][/org/kde/fstab///192.168.5.1]
EverMounted=true
LastSeenMounted=true
```

KDE was, for some reason remouting my share.
Notice that this file was on my home folder, of my normal user, not root.

Just deleted that group and I was finally able to unmount the share!

Let's see it it holds...